# json string to object with unknowns

Tags: java, json, string

As the title describes I'm trying to assign a json string to my class, but the json string will presumably contain several variables which I have not created in the class they are being assigned to.

To show you first what works, I have

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try {

        Tweet tweet1 = mapper
                .readValue(
                        "{\"created_at\":\"Sat Feb 08 11:26:02 +0000 2014\"}",
                        Tweet.class);

    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

That works, as the class, Tweet, has the variable "created_at" with getter and setter methods all in place.

Like mentioned though, I need to expect the string in the readValue method to contain things which are not to be found in my Tweet class.

To get around this, I import and use:

```
    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
```

Which theoretically helps me avoid all the unknowns in there, and just assigns the values that are to be found in the Tweet class.

So, I add a value which is not to be found in Tweet, like so:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

    try {

        Tweet tweet1 = mapper
                .readValue(
                        "{\"created_at\":\"Sat Feb 08 11:26:02 +0000 2014\",\"id\":432113085571407872\"}",
                        Tweet.class);

    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Now, the value "id" does not exist in my Tweet class, and should therefor be ignored (no?).

But, now the console throws me an error:

**com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@7817ea54; line: 1, column: 72]**

Now this makes me a sad panda, because I cannot for the life of me understand what it is I'm doing wrong.

Anyone with better eyes and/or a sharper mind than mine, see my mistake?

Or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid. Here's the value of the id attribute:

```
432113085571407872\"
```

You see that either it has a quote missing at the beginning, or it has a quote that shouldn't be there at the end.

That's what the error message says, BTW:

> Unexpected character ('"'

Comment: Dammit, was it that simple? I swear, I need new glasses. Thanks though, I'll make your answer the correct one!